# How to finish Activity when starting other activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I  have problems to finish the activity before. I want to start another activity and finish the current activity. When I used `finish` it didn't exit the current activity.

How can I exit the activity before?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
         startActivity(intent);
         finish();

Comment: You mean so there is no chance the two activities are running at the same time, sounds like you will need a third party to start the second activity if the first one is dead.  If so you are probably going to need some kind of service with a timer of sorts.

Comment: will finish() take the activity directly to onDestroy() from onResume() ?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You need to `intent` your current `context` to another activity first with `startActivity`. After that you can `finish` your current `activity` from where you redirect.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);// New activity
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish(); // Call once you redirect to another activity
```

`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` - Clears the activity stack. If you don't want to clear the activity stack. PLease don't use that flag then.

Comment: why we use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP @vikalp patel??

Comment: It makes sure that you cannot go back to the previous activity with the BACK button.

Comment: You could also use the method `@Override public void onBackPressed()` to define specific behaviour you want on the back button press (leaving it blank stops it from going back to the previous activity as well).

Comment: why do we need the finish() if  FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP clears the stack

Answer (score 9):

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,NewLaunchingActivity.Class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // Call Only, if you wants to clears the activity stack else ignore it. 
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
```

Add Intent Flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`  if you want to clear the activity stack else ignore it. Read more about this [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).

Answer (score 8):

The best - and simplest - solution might be this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finishAndRemoveTask();
```

Documentation for `finishAndRemoveTask()`:

> Call this when your activity is done and should be closed and the task should be completely removed as a part of finishing the root activity of the task.

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make your activity A in manifest file: `launchMode = "singleInstance"`
2. When the user clicks new, do `FirstActivity.fa.finish();` and call the new Intent.
3. When the user clicks modify, call the new Intent or simply finish activity B.

Answer (score 1):

```
startActivity(new Intent(context, ListofProducts.class)
    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 1):

simple example of this can be (Kotlin)

```
val intent = intent(this,exampleSecondActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
finsih() //this will do all the work for you
```

It works of me when i navigate to home screen from splash activity

Answer (score -1):

For eg: you are using two activity, if you want to switch over from Activity A to Activity B

Simply give like this.

```
          Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
         startActivity(intent);
         finish();
```

Comment: Finish will not instantly terminate current activity. It is just a signal.