# How to start an activity in finish()

Tags: java, android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I want to start another activity in `finish()` depending on a condition. I got the same code working in `onDestroy()` but I think this is not the right place from the lifecycle point of view.

(Activities might be destroyed, although there were not actively left by the user).

The following code did not have any effect:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    if (mCondition) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    super.finish();
}
```

Why is it not working, are there alternatives?

Comment: What did you do to trigger this?  Are you certain `finish()` is being called.  If it is, was there a an error printed in the log?

Comment: @couling You are right, finish it not being called, I haven't done it explicitly yet.

Comment: @Mahoni : why don't you try this in `onPause()` any specific reason

Comment: please see the accepted answer of [what exactly Activity.finish() method is doing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847526/what-exactly-activity-finish-method-is-doing)

Comment: Are you calling finish() at any given point in your application? If not, then this method will not be called since it is not part of the Activity lifecycle. That is why it works in onDestroy() which is part of the lifecycle. Can I ask what workflow you want in your application - that would make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is starting the new activity then finish the current one:

```
if (mCondition) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: But then it wouldn't be finished on other occasions, would it? I see no difference between this code and mine, except that a plain invocation to `finish()` instead of `super.finish()` would lead to infinite recursion.

Comment: It's not the most clear answer. The difference is where this code is placed.  The suggestion is to move the code out of the `finish()` function and into whatever functions call it.

Comment: @Mahoni, would lead to infinite recursion and in your code you are finishing the activity before starting the new one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957125/how-to-finish-activity-when-starting-other-activity-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I have Used Myself this and it is working fine

```
   public void ToBeClosed()
    {
        Intent a = new Intent(context,NewActivity.class);
        startActivity(a);
        OldActivity.this.finish();
    }
```

and use the function in if statement body

```
 if (mCondition) { ToBeClosed(); }
```