# Action Bar does not Recreate on Activity Recreate Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, locale

I am changing the language of my application based on user input.
 After this I have to recreate the activity for the changes to be visible. I have till now tried two approaches :

1. **1st Approach:**

   ```
             Intent refresh = getIntent();
             finish();
             startActivity(refresh);
   ```

But the thing is that though the activity loads with the new language strings the action bar title remains in the previous language. If I close the application and load the screen again everything is fine. 
So I thought I might be doing something wrong and changed the code to :

2. **Second Approach:**

   ```
   Intent refresh = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.Class);
   refresh.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   startActivity(refresh);
   finish();
   ```

   See [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18957237/4282901).

This causes the application to crash. Any insights would be really helpful.

**Note:**
I am using app.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity

**Problem ScreenShot:**
[image: Action bar Title not recreated]

**EDIT:**

I have also tried:

```
 Intent refresh =getIntent();
         finish(); 
         this.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
          startActivity(refresh);
```

The problem still persists.

**EDIT 2:**
Used :

```
Intent refresh =getIntent();
         if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
               supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();

            else
               invalidateOptionsMenu();

         //this.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
         //finish(); 

          startActivity(refresh);
          finish();
```

Still the issue persists.

Comment: please call `finish()` after `startActivity()`

Answer (score 1):

You can ask android to re-create the actionbar before it automatically does by calling `invalidateOptionsMenu();`

example:

```
 // whatever you want to do before you want to recreate action bar

activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

** **EDIT** **

On API < 11 use `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` method

Complete solution would be something like this:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
   supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();

else
   invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Comment: My min sdk version is 7. So cant use invalidateOptionsMenu :( this was introduced in API 11

Comment: call `this.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();` before calling`finish()` and please use the conditional statement like my updated Answer

Comment: @ Syed Osama Maruf, can you show the error stack trace that you face ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79190/discussion-between-syed-osama-maruf-and-sharp-edge).

Answer (score 0):

After recreating Activity try in `onCreate` method set action bar title just like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    resetTitle();
}
...
private void resetTitle() {
    try {
        int label = getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(getComponentName(), GET_META_DATA).labelRes;
        if (label != 0) {
            if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(label));
            } else {
                setTitle(label);
            }
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Reset title problem", e);
    }
}
```

By the way, you can also use the [`recreate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29) method to recreate activity. It is added in API level 11.