# Have Activity A and B in activity

Tags: android, json

I Have Activity A and B. In activity A , I load data then when click on the list it move me to activity B. When go back to activity A the data load again. How to prevent this ?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to finish Activity when starting other activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957125/how-to-finish-activity-when-starting-other-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you move from one activity to another, say from activity A to activity B, then the data which you have loaded gets lost. To prevent the data reloading, you need to override onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstance).

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
  // killed and restarted.
  savedInstanceState.putBoolean("MyBoolean", true);
  savedInstanceState.putDouble("myDouble", 1.9);
  savedInstanceState.putInt("MyInt", 1);
  savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", "Welcome back to Android");
  // etc.
}
```

And you can extract those values by overriding onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstance).

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
  boolean myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("MyBoolean");
  double myDouble = savedInstanceState.getDouble("myDouble");
  int myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyInt");
  String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyString");
}
```

Also you can store and retrieve the arraylist.